# How i can load chat-history with array, Socket.IO

Tags: javascript, mysql, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I have chat on Socket.IO, MySQL, PHP. Everything is working good, but i need download and diplay messages history when you update the page.

php code:

```
<script>var USER = {"id":"<?php echo $_SESSION['steamid']?>","login":"<?php echo $_SESSION['personaname']?>","image":"<?php echo $_SESSION['avatarmedium']?>","hash":"<?php echo md5($_SESSION['steamid']) ?>"};</script>
```

js site code:

```
var messageTpl = _.template($("#chat-message").html());

function sendMessage(text) {
    socket.emit('message', {user: USER, message: text});
}
var lastUser = null;
function addMessage(data, checkLast) {

    var a = $("#chatScroll")[0];
    var isScrollDown = (a.offsetHeight + a.scrollTop) == a.scrollHeight;

    if (checkLast && lastUser && lastUser.id == data.user.id) {
        $('.chatMessage').last().find('.body').append('<br/>' + _.escape(data.message))
    }
    else {
        console.log(data);
        data.user.url = 'http://steamcommunity.com/profiles/' + data.user.id;
        data.user.image = 'https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/' + _.escape(data.user.image).replace('_medium', '');
        var html = messageTpl(data);
        $('#messages').append(html);
        if ($('.chatMessage').length > 100) {
            $('.chatMessage').eq(0).remove();
        }
    }
    lastUser = data.user;

    if (isScrollDown) a.scrollTop = a.scrollHeight;
    $("#chatScroll").perfectScrollbar();
}
socket.on('online', function(data) {
    $('#online').text(data.online);
});
socket.on('chat-message', function(data) {
    addMessage(data, true);
});
socket.on('chat-history', _.once(function(data) {
    $("#chatScroll").perfectScrollbar();
    if (data) _.each(data, addMessage);
}));
```

function `addMessage` works good, but with `socket.on('chat-history')` i got error 
`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`

js server code:

```
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM cs_chat ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 50', function(error, rows) {
        if(!error) {
            var user = [];
              rows.forEach(function (data) {
                  user.push(data);
                });
            console.log(user);
            socket.emit('chat-history', {user: JSON.stringify(user)});
        } else {
            console.log(error.message);
        }
    });
```

when you refresh the page - all last messages lost
console.log server js rows.forEach below.

```
  [{"id":668,"message_text":"3qwe","user_steamid":"76561198056267433","user_personaname":"@Saundefined","date":"2015-10-06T15:22:15.000Z","user_avatarmedium":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/c2/c2ff9427410ea1121363de0e651f6d4e8c485ab6_medium.jpg"},{"id":667,"message_text":"12312","user_steamid":"76561198056267433","user_personaname":"@Saundefined","date":"2015-10-06T15:22:14.000Z","user_avatarmedium":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/c2/c2ff9427410ea1121363de0e651f6d4e8c485ab6_medium.jpg"},{"id":666,"message_text":"213123","user_steamid":"76561198056267433","user_personaname":"@Saundefined","date":"2015-10-06T15:22:14.000Z","user_avatarmedium":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/c2/c2ff9427410ea1121363de0e651f6d4e8c485ab6_medium.jpg"},{"id":665,"message_text":"cvb","user_steamid":"76561198056267433","user_personaname":"@Saundefined","date":"2015-10-06T15:22:12.000Z","user_avatarmedium":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/c2/c2ff9427410ea1121363de0e651f6d4e8c485ab6_medium.jpg"},{"id":664,"message_text":"cvb","user_steamid":"76561198056267433","user_personaname":"@Saundefined","date":"2015-10-06T15:22:12.000Z","user_avatarmedium":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/c2/c2ff9427410ea1121363de0e651f6d4e8c485ab6_medium.jpg"},{"id":663,"message_text":"g","user_steamid":"76561198056267433","user_personaname":"@Saundefined","date":"2015-10-06T15:22:12.000Z","user_avatarmedium":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/c2/c2ff9427410ea1121363de0e651f6d4e8c485ab6_medium.jpg"},{"id":662,"message_text":"gdf","user_steamid":"76561198056267433","user_personaname":"@Saundefined","date":"2015-10-06T15:22:12.000Z","user_avatarmedium":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/c2/c2ff9427410ea1121363de0e651f6d4e8c485ab6_medium.jpg"},{"id":661,"message_text":"df","user_steamid":"76561198056267433","user_personaname":"@Saundefined","date":"2015-10-06T15:22:12.000Z","user_avatarmedium":"https://steamcdn-a.akamaihd.net/steamcommunity/public/images/avatars/c2/c2ff9427410ea1121363de0e651f6d4e8c485ab6_medium.jpg"}]
```

Comment: why not just cache the incoming message on the client and populate onload with the saved messages?

Comment: @dandavis , cache is a bad option when online 500-1000.

Comment: you call `JSON.stringify`, but not JSON.parse. it looks like you should pass a real object instead of a string as the user property value in chat-history's event object.

Comment: @dandavis , i try parse .... crash :( http://c2n.me/3otMcrt

Comment: no, just emit the object. the literal "JSON" should not appear anywhere...

Comment: @dandavis i do not understand